# print a downloaded file out in the console

Tags: java

i have a simple http client server. here client can download from the server. From my code client can download the file. That's basically means a file from server folder is transferred  to the client successfully. What i want to do is to also show the downloaded file in the console. My question is how can i modify my code that is also shows the received file out the console.

My server:

```
public class Fileagent extends Thread
      {
            Socket client;

            DataInputStream din;
            DataOutputStream dout;
            ServerSocket soc;
            PrintWriter w;
            BufferedReader r;
 public Fileagent(Socket soc)
      {
               try
        {
                 client=soc;      
                 din=new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                 dout=new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                 w = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                 r= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                 BufferedReader con = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

          start();

         } ..................





            public void upload() throws Exception
         {  


           String file=din.readUTF();
           File f=new File(file);
           System.out.println("\nThe client requested to download the file"+" "+f);
           boolean exsists=check(f);

          if (exsists==false){
                System.out.println("File not found in server");
                out.writeUTF("ERROR");//if not found sends an ERROR message
             return;
            }
         else
            {
             dout.writeUTF("FOUND");//if found in server sends a FOUND message.

           FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(f);
          int ch;
            //reads and sends the file
         do
         {
          ch=fin.read();
           dout.writeUTF(String.valueOf(ch));
        }
        while(ch!=-1); 
        fin.close(); 
          dout.writeUTF("File Receive Successfully"); 
        }
         }


        public Boolean check(File file){

        if(file.exists())
        {
           return true;
         }
             else
       {

        return false;
        }
       }
```

The client code to download:

```
                  public void download(Socket s) throws Exception{


         DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
          DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
         BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
          BufferedReader con = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
          String request;
            System.out.print("Enter File Name :");



        request=con.readLine();
        dout.writeUTF(request);
       String msg=din.readUTF();


        if(msg.compareTo("ERROR")==0)
       {
          System.out.println("File not found on Server ...");
        return;
        }
       else if(msg.compareTo("FOUND")==0)    
  {
        System.out.println("Receiving File ...");
        File f=new File(request);
        String option;
        boolean exsists=check(f);
        if(exsists==true)
      {
        String Option;
          System.out.println("File Already Exists. Want to OverWrite (Y/N) ?");

         Option=con.readLine();   
           if(Option=="N") 
            {
         dout.flush();
           return; 
           }

         }


         FileOutputStream fileout=new FileOutputStream(f);
         int ch;
         String temp;
    do
   {
         temp=din.readUTF();
         ch=Integer.parseInt(temp);
         if(ch!=-1)
  {
    fileout.write(ch);     
   }
  }while(ch!=-1);
  fileout.close();
  System.out.println(din.readUTF());
   System.out.println("success");
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your do while loop of client code, add System.out.write():

```
do {
    temp=din.readUTF();
    ch=Integer.parseInt(temp);

    if (ch!=-1) {
        fileout.write(ch);     
        System.out.write(ch);
    }
} while(ch!=-1);
```